# Hierarchical groupings as subordinate, superordinate, and... lateral-ordinate?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a hierarchical model which differentiates between elements (e.g., workers) under a focal element, above it, parallel to it, and considers all elements regardless of position.

It has been a bit of a struggle to find cohesive and understandable terms for these four groupings. At the moment, I have settled for subordinate, lateral, super-ordinate, and overall. These are understandable in this context, but not entirely cohesive. Super- and subordinate are perfect as they denote higher and lower in rank, respectively. But I cannot find a word indicating a rank equivalence (lateral, horizontal, parallel). Is there such a word in the suffix+*ordinate* realm, or any other?

Comment: Use the metaphoric "family" model (elements have ***parents, children,*** and ***siblings***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for the suggestion! It does fit, but if we are talking about employees, than it becomes a bit odd speaking of subordinates as children etc.., doesn't it?

Comment: It's a common metaphor, no one will think it strange.

Comment: Equals or Peers?

Comment: What does the phrase "focal element" mean? For example, in the case of employees?

Comment: That is just the relational term - one employee's superordinates are another employee's subordinates, or peers.

Comment: Kindly clarify your question more. If you want terms for employees in an organisation, army jargon would be good place to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Coordinate!**

Merriam-Webster's first definition: equal in rank, quality, or significance

Comment: +1. Afraid it may cause confusion with the coordinating type meaning. As a non-native speaker I never knew this meaning of the word! But strictly speaking this answers my question. Thanks!